# When Rails app is accessed from a new terminal, all gems are deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rubygems, ubuntu-14.04

This bizarre...I replaced the hard drive on my computer and reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04, and cloned my Rails app. I set it all up, ran bundle install, and everything went fine.

But when I open a new terminal and access the app from it, the new terminal thinks that my app doesn't have any gems installed. Even `rails -v` returns

```
$ rails -v
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

and `bundle install` returns

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

But on the terminal I used to set up my app (both terminals are open at the same time) if I run `rails -v` I get the normal output "Rails 4.0.10
", and `bundle install` executes normally.

I'm pretty sure if I were to quit out of the terminal I used to set it up, all the changes I've made to my app would be reverted for good, but I don't want to test that theory.

How is it possible for two simultaneous terminals to see a project differently??

**Output of `rvm list` for BOTH terminals**

```
$ rvm list


rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p643 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

---

**UPDATE**

I closed all open terminals and opened up a new one, and reinstalled RVM and ruby. No matter how many times I do this, `ruby -v` always returns

```
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

but `rvm install 2.0.0` returns

```
Already installed ruby-2.0.0-p643.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p643
```

Comment: Use rvm, select from the list `rvm list`

Comment: @Prashant4224 Both terminals give the same output. I posted the result.

Comment: Go through this [gnome-terminal with rvm](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal)

Answer (score 2):

Your rvm setup isn't right. A new terminal is running the rvm shims (paths to rvm ruby and gems), and the old terminal is pointing to a different ruby version, maybe even the system ruby; or vice versa.

Close all terminals, start a fresh one, check to see if RVM is set up correctly with the bash hooks; then bundle install.

Comment: How do I check if RVM is set up correctly? What do you mean by bash hooks?

Comment: https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting - just the first section. It's likely that any terminal you used to install rvm won't work. You should run `ruby -v` and `which ruby` to see which version of ruby your particular terminal window is using.

Comment: Where can I find the "shell configuration files" that it's talking about?

Comment: in your home ~ directory, but i'd say the best bet is that you just had to open a new terminal window to get your rvm working after installing it. `ruby -v` and `which ruby` will tell you if that's the case.

Comment: `ruby -v` returns "ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]", which is strange because I ran `rvm install 2.0.0` to install it.

Comment: then you're probably using system ruby in that terminal. try a new window, if it's still 1.9.3 then your rvm just isn't loading as part of .bash_profile or .bashrc, in which case (in the absence of errors when loading that new term window) I suggest reinstalling rvm.

Comment: Huh. I opened a new window and reinstalled rvm, and `ruby -v` still returns "ruby 1.9.3".